# Differences between OsmAnd and OsmAnd+

Tags: osmand

What is the difference between the free version of [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) and the Plus version?

[The only info I found](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/osmand/vC0I1xgtddo) seems to be outdated. While using the free edition the only limitation I noticed was the hint that I can only download 10 different maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today (24/03/2016), OsmAnd has 3 versions publicly available. This is possible because OsmAnd is [GPL software](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/blob/master/LICENSE), and therefore can be freely compiled and distributed.

1: [Developers' free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand), crippled to 10 downloads and no Wikipedia capability.

2: [Developers' paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus), uncrippled.

3: [F-Droid version](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.osmand.plus), uncrippled but has slower updates than the paid version.

Comment: There's also the nightly build, available here. http://download.osmand.net/latest-night-build/ I don't think it has any limits on downloads etc. And it is the most up to date, though may be unstable/buggy.

Answer (score 6):

As of 28/03/2013 the difference is that with the free version is limited to a total of 10 downloads (maps, voice packages, etc) and does not support offline Wikipedia content.

I know because I tried the free version and then buyed the plus one to be able to download entire european countries. Also I think is a really good application for 7 euros.

Comment: 10 downloads: Do you mean that when you have downloaded 10 times you are done, and can't download anymore even after deleting downloaded data?

Answer (score 4):

There exist 3 Versions of Osmand

The Market free Version: full featured

The Market Plus version: full featured, used as a way to donate to the developers as incentive to keep on improving.

The F-Droid Version: A source compiled free software version by fdroid with almost no changes to the normal version. Not so frequent app updates. The maps are updated the same way as in the offical build.

Do not under any circumstances install two versions at the same time, it will seriously destroy both of the apps, the map files on sd, your sanity and your battery power.

Comment: Didn't know of the conflicts between different versions. Don't taking any chances anyway, thanks!

Comment: The Market free version has both the 10 downloads limitation and the offline wikipedia content limitation mentioned above. Do you know if the f-droid version has neither of these limitations?

Comment: I know the F-Droid version does *not* have the download limitation. I downloaded all 50 states with no problem. However, I don't know if it uses wikipedia, since I've never used that feature (and didn't know about it until seeing this question). I would guess that it doesn't have that limitation either.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I just downloaded the Market free version and it had limited functionality described in the other answer.